# Crashing after reading with cin

Tags: c++, crash, cin

For some reason the program always crashes the second time I main calls `inputHolding()` and tries to get the call number (the call number is entered and then it crashes).  How do I fix this crash? Here is a picture of the call stack and where it is crashing in my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0HSX.png

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LibraryDrv.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
Holding *hptr[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hptr[i] = inputHolding();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hptr[i]->print();
}

return 0;
}

Holding* inputHolding() {
char selection;
char title[50];
int callNumber = 0;
char author[50];
char performer[50];
char format;

cout << "Enter B for book, R for recording: ";
cin >> selection;

if (selection == 'B') {
    cout << "Enter book title: ";
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Enter book author: ";
    cin >> author;

    cout << "Enter call number: ";
    cin >> callNumber;

    Book* aBook = new Book(title, callNumber, author);
    return aBook;
}
else  if (selection == 'R') {
    cout << "Enter recording title: ";
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Enter performer: ";
    cin >> performer;

    cout << "Enter format: (M)P3, (W)AV, (A)IFF: ";
    cin >> format;

    cout << "Enter call number: ";
    cin >> callNumber;

    Recording* aRecording = new Recording(title, callNumber, performer,     format);
    return aRecording;
}
else {
    cout << "Incorrect selection" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use std::string rather than char array? What happens if the title entered is more than 49 characters?

Comment: Can you post the full code??